# @bind-Value:event="oninput" does not work for InputText blazor component?

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I'm new to blazor but I'm unable to understand why oninput event does not work for **InputText** blazor component but works for HTML **input** tag. And if possible also help me understand the following errors. I'm using .NET 8 Blazor Server app.

Thanks!

Data/customer.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TestApp2.Data
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public Boolean Archived { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Pages/CustomerView.razor (E.g. 1 - bind:event)

```
@page "/customer"
@using TestApp2.Data

<h3>Customers</h3>

<EditForm Model="@customerRecord" FormName="CutomerEntry">
    <InputText @bind="customerRecord.CustomerName" @bind:event="oninput" />
</EditForm>

@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@customerRecord.CustomerName))
{
    <div>
        <span> Customer Name: </span> <span>@customerRecord.CustomerName </span>

    </div>
}


@code {
    public Customer customerRecord { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => customerRecord ??= new();
    
}
```

Console Error:

```
 Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputText requires a value for the 'ValueExpression' parameter. Normally this is provided automatically when using 'bind-Value'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputBase`1.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)
```

So, tried using bind-Value instead but then got a different error

Pages/CustomerView.razor (E.g. 2 - bind-Value:event) - changed the following line from E.g. 1

```
<EditForm Model="@customerRecord" FormName="CutomerEntry">
    <InputText @bind-Value="customerRecord.CustomerName" @bind-Value:event="oninput" />
</EditForm>
```

Console Error:

```
Error: System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object& value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithOneArg(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackWorkItem.InvokeAsync[T](MulticastDelegate delegate, T arg)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.DispatchEventAsync(UInt64 eventHandlerId, EventFieldInfo fieldInfo, EventArgs eventArgs, Boolean waitForQuiescence)
```

Pages/CustomerView.razor (E.g. 3 - ) - changed the following line from E.g. 1

```
<EditForm Model="@customerRecord" FormName="CutomerEntry">
    <input @bind="customerRecord.CustomerName" @bind:event="oninput" />
</EditForm>
```

No errors works fine but is not InputText component which I guess is more optimized for blazor?

Comment: The benefit of InputText is that it automatically hooks into Blazor's validation system. With a normal <input> tag, you'd need to invoke the validation manually. Having said that, I don't have a good answer to your question, though I'd like to see one.

Answer (score 0):

We usually don't need to bind event ourself when we use InputText component,we just need to call `@bind-Value`,the codes inside the component would handle the event for us,If you do want to bind an event to  InputText  component,you may try :

```
<EditForm Model="@customerRecord" FormName="CutomerEntry">
   
    <InputText @bind-Value="customerRecord.CustomerName" @oninput="OnInput"  @onblur="OnBlur"></InputText>
    
</EditForm>

@code{
    ............
    private void OnBlur(FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
    
    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
    
    }

}
```